# URLConnection in java

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList containing list of websites in this format:-

- google.com
- facebook.com
- youtube.com
- yahoo.com
- wikipedia.org
- t.co

  And I have to read html text from all the links. But some links are creating problem like (t.co) and other are working fine.

  Code:-

  ```
             try
                    {
                      String line="t.co";
                      String[] Add_words = line.split("[//:.]");
                      if (Add_words[0].contains("http")) {

                      }

                      else if (Add_words[0].contains("www"))
                          line = "http://" + line;
                      else if (!Add_words[0].contains("http")
                              && !Add_words[0].contains("www"))
                          line = "http://www." + line;


                       URL url = new URL(line);
                       URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                       HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                       if(urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection)
                       {
                          connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                          System.out.println("Please enter an HTTP URL.");
                          return;
                       }
                       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                       new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                       String urlString = "";
                       String current;
                       while((current = in.readLine()) != null)
                       {
                          urlString += current+"\n";
                       }
                       System.out.println(urlString);
                    }catch(IOException e)
                    {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }


  And I'm getting the error with the last link `t.co`
  ```

  error:-

  ```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.t.co
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1834)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
      at com.test.code.Main.main(Main.java:109)
  ```

  What i need is, I have list of link in above format and my code should access all the link, whatever the link format will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `www.` to `t.co`, but `www.t.co` is not correct and will result in an `404 Not Found`.

Just do not add the `www.` to the URL and it should work.

Comment: Sorry I did not see this when I posted mine.

Comment: @Tim, i have a list of lots of link . so how can i do for every one .

Comment: Not sure what the question is now, but if you just replace `line = "http://www." + line;` by `line = "http://" + line;` it should work. Why do you have to append the `www.`?

Answer (score 0):

You get `FileNotFoundException` because getting a response from `http://www.t.co` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: i have a list of lots of link of this type  . so how can i do for every one.

Comment: If `url.openConnection()` throws an `Exception`, that means the `url` is unreachable/invalid. Move on to the next one. Or don't create invalid/false urls in the first place.

Comment: for testing view i can handle it but how can a user know. If they have a list like this. then

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, please clarify.

Comment: The overall idea is :- you have a list of link in csv file. you just upload it. my code will access all those links and will keep in ArrayList and link will be any in format like without http, www or may be prefixed by https. so I have to validate all the links. if link is working then access the html text if not then move to next link..

Comment: And what's wrong then with what I said in my first comment?

Comment: But you are already catching the `Exception`. Just do nothing, proceed to the next URL.

Comment: its terminating my database connect. I can't move to next link.

Comment: And how would I know that when you didn't posted the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `www.` to your `t.co` link which is causing the problem. Do not add that prefix and only try with `http://t.co` and it should work if your link is **valid**.

**EDIT**

Change:

```
else if (Add_words[0].contains("www"))
     line = "http://" + line;
else if (!Add_words[0].contains("http")
         && !Add_words[0].contains("www"))
      line = "http://www." + line;
```

to

```
else if (Add_words[0].contains("www") ||
         (line.contains("t.co") && !Add_words[0].contains("www")))
     line = "http://" + line;
else if (!Add_words[0].contains("http")
         && !Add_words[0].contains("www")
         && !line.contains("t.co"))
      line = "http://www." + line;
```

This is not the best way but will do. The only case left is if you have `line=www.t.co` in which you will need to remove the `www.` prefix before those if statements. 
As @Tim said `www.` append is unnessecary anyway so the most efficient solution will be fixing the second `else if` as he suggested.